# Python compressing rows by multiple columns - groupby drops groups which it shouldn't?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not yet able to reproduce the error with a random set of data...only with the data itself. Maybe you can help me in reproducing it.

I have a dataframe with over 99 mostly categorical columns and one summable column `'100_Quantity'`. Overall it's > 1Mio rows. Not all possible combinations of column values do contain a figure in `'100_quantity'` but there are no NaNs in `'100_quantity'`  in the original data.

For the sake of simplification I describe 3 out of the 99 columns.

3 out of these 99 are `['78_SunHours', '8_Country', '9_Region']`
There are two in these 99 columns, call them `['8_Country','9_Region']` which are the most important.

I need to group by all columns and sum the `'100_Quantity'`. Thus reducing the rows to the meaningful combinations of the 99 Column Values (i.e. where a value exists in the df)
Focusing at `'8_Country'` and `'9_Region'`, it should look like

```
*8_Country*,*9_Region*,..., *78_SunHours*, ..., *100_Quantity*
USA, West, ..., 9, ..., 5.5 --- 1 ---
USA, East, ..., 0, ..., 120.6 --- 2 ---
USA, North, ..., 0, ..., 0 --- 3 ---
USA, South, ..., 76, ..., 0.000000001 --- 4 ---
```

--- 1 --- many rows in original data

--- 2 --- many rows in original data

--- 3 --- many rows, sum up to zero

--- 4 --- many rows, almost sum up to zero

However, it returns something like

```
*8_Country*,*9_Region*,..., *78_SunHours*, ..., *100_Quantity*
USA, West, ..., 9, ..., 5.5
USA, East, ..., 0, ..., 120.6
-- end --
```

The Problem is, although I want to have this row reduction, also some groups's rows get completely dropped and I don' know why.

e.g. looking at the data with another tool, excel, only at ['8_Country','9_Region', '100_Quantity'] returns the last row.

```
USA, West, ..., 9, ..., 5.5
USA, East, ..., 0, ..., 120.6
USA, North, ..., 0, ..., 0
USA, South, ..., 76, ..., 0.000000001
```

Note2: I don't need all combinations with zeros. Just the combinations from `['8_Country','9_Region']` which is *a subset* of the over 99 columns - but I still need the 97 remaining.

I used multiple groupby statements. I cannot really reproduce the behaviour with a smaller dataset.

Using excel's pivot function, I can create the results. Since then I know the groups dropped also (randomly!) contain smaller results.

```
df.groupby([99 columns])['100_Quantity'].sum()
```

also

```
df.groupby([99 columns], as_axis=False, sort=False)['100_Quantity'].sum()
```

Only looking at Country and Region, it should look like

```
*8_Country*,*9_Region*,..., *78_SunHours*, ..., *100_Quantity*
USA, West, ..., 9, ..., 5.5
USA, East, ..., 0, ..., 120.6
USA, North, ..., 0, ..., 0
USA, South, ..., 76, ..., 0.000000001
```

However, it returns something like

```
*8_Country*,*9_Region*,..., *78_SunHours*, ..., *100_Quantity*
USA, West, ..., 9, ..., 5.5
USA, East, ..., 0, ..., 120.6
-- end --
```

Comment: Interesting, I have added a 'Dummy' column of 1.0 values to the large df. ˋˋˋresult = df.groupby([99 columns], as_axis=False, sort=False)['100_Quantity', 'Dummy'].sum()ˋˋˋ that leads to the following result: ˋˋˋdf.loc[:,'Dummy'].sum()ˋˋˋ is significantly higher than ˋˋˋresult.loc[:,'Dummy'].sum()ˋˋˋ

Comment: I'm not following with your question 100% but are you sure your dtypes are correct? check those before you do any mathematical operations.

Comment: Hi, thank you! the 99 columns are mostly of dtype=object. 100_Quantity is a float64. When I change columns to dtype=category groupby immediately gets stuck. I will probably add an example - unfortunately one which cant reproduce the issue.

Comment: and in that sense, the dtypes are correct ... :/

Comment: I'm still having a hard time conceptualising your issue. Why don't you re-do your question with your raw_input (a few rows will do) then the steps you have taken along with the code you've tried. and your intended output. One of the pros here will be able to help you.

Comment: will add a few rows